# Install a Python package and debug it

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I have the following use case:
I want to write some code that uses a package from GitHub, while debugging that package. I cloned that package next to the directory with my code, so the directory structure looks like this:

```
/code
  /github-package
  /my-code
```

The package comes with a `setup.py` file that users `setuptools.setup` method, and I install it using:

```bash
$ python setup.py install
```

the package is installed and I can import it.
However, when I run my code, I can't debug the package (I can't step into it while debugging).
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: What type of package are you using? some packages are pure python and should be able to be debugged, but some are using the c interface and can not be fully debugged using a python debugger. an example that can not easily be debugged is numpy.

Comment: I'm using VSCode.
The package is 100% Python.

Comment: In your `launch.json` set `justMyCode` to false. see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_justmycode